# How to read the xml tags in java

Tags: java, xml

Hi I have an xml as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<A>
    <B>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZZsaqw</Name>
        </X1>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZZsdasda</Name>
        </X1>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZZsdsd</Name>
        </X1>
        <S>17000</S>
        <U>18000</U>
        <V>17000</V>
    <B>
    <C>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZZasqw</Name>
        </X1>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZZsdsd</Name>
        </X1>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZ</Name>
        </X1>
        <S>17000</S>
        <U>18000</U>
        <V>17000</V>
    <C>
    <D>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZZx</Name>
        </X1>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZZzz</Name>
        </X1>
        <X1>
            <Name>ZZZsaa</Name>
        </X1>
        <S>17000</S>
        <U>18000</U>
        <V>17000</V>
    </D>
<A>
```

I am interested in the X1 tag. I need to read them respective of their parent tags which can be either B, C or D. 
So at times I am interested only in X1 tags belonging to B sometimes belonging to C. How to do this? I used the DOM parser shown below but when I am counting them, it is showing the count as 9 where as it should have been 3. Please help me how to do it.

```
        NodeList plist = doc.getElementsByTagName("A");
        System.out.println("The length of A is pList is:"+plist.getLength());
        //get the contents of the A
        for (int temp = 0; temp < plist.getLength(); temp++)
        {
            Node nNode = plist.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                //Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                NodeList typicalCriticalPath = doc.getElementsByTagName("B");
                System.out.println("The length of B is:"+typicalCriticalPath.getLength());

                //get the contents of the typical critical path
                for(int temp1 = 0; temp1<typicalCriticalPath.getLength();temp1++)
                {
                    Node typCriticalPathNode = typicalCriticalPath.item(temp);
                    if (typCriticalPathNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {
                        Element ele = (Element) typCriticalPathNode;
                        NodeList planItemSection = doc.getElementsByTagName("X1");
                        System.out.println("The length of X1 is:"+planItemSection.getLength());
                    }

                }

            }
        }
 //The output for this is like this-
 //The length of A is pList is:1
 //The length of B is:1
 //The length of X1 is:9
```

Can someone please point me where I am going wrong? What is to be done so that I can get the tags wrt parent tag only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NodeList planItemSection = doc.getElementsByTagName("X1");

That would be all X1 in the document.

I think you want

> NodeList planItemSection = ele.getElementsByTagName("X1");

, where `ele` is the parent element.

You may also want to look into XPath for these kind of queries.